# package in google colab

Tags: python, package, google-colaboratory, kora

simple question:

does different notebooks in google colab share the same package?

[image]

I run `!pip list`, and I want to find `Kora`, which is a module that I just installed by `!pip Kora`.
As you can see, I can find `kora` from one notebook, but can't find it in another notebook. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install it each time in every new notebooks.